# How can I give primary key and foreign key relationship in Sequelize.js + Postgres.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am not able to give relationship into to two tables User and Media
User have profile field which should contain Media Id.

Right now I have written these models User and Media now I want to fetch data using join query.

**USER MODEL**

```
const User = sequelize.sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastName: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    media_id: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        foreignKey: true
    }
});

Media.belongsTo(User, {
    as: 'media',
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'media_id',
        allowNull: false
    }
});

User.find({where: {}, include: [Media]})
User.sync();
```

**MEDIA MODEL**

```
const Media = sequelize.sequelize.define('media', {
    id: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    path: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    type: {
        type: sequelize.Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

Media.sync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Media.belongsTo(User...)` will add a field `media_id` to your `Media` model, which is not what you want. Try instead:

```
User.belongsTo(Media, {
    as: 'media',
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'media_id',
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

Then, you should modify your query:

```
// Find all users with media where media.id === user.media_id
User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Media,
        where: { id: Sequelize.col('user.media_id') }
    }]
})
```

Comment: Getting this

Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: media is not associated to users!